# Rails DB error in collumn in rails_admin

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

Добрый день. Никак не могу понять что я накосячил в своем велосипеде, и почему возникает эта ошибка

```
gist.github.com/iLucker93/8a98698e13471d0a247d34614ab9b75d это мой лог файл
```

## views/ua/rates.html.erb

```
    <div class="content_name">
        <h3>Тарифні плани</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
                <%= render :partial => 'ua_rates/ua_rates_index'%>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-3 col-sm-11 col-sm-push-1 col-xs-12">
            <h4>​До кожного тарифного плану входить:</h4>
            <ul>
                <li>24/7 доступ до web APIs</li>
                <li>Необмежена кількість внесення змін до дизайну Пассу</li>
                <li>До 10 геоміток для кожного Пассу</li>
                <li>Необмежена кількість Email повідомлень</li>
                <li>Необмежена кількість Push повідомлень на екран клієнта</li>
                <li>Можливість розповсюдження за допомогою QR-коду та web-лінків</li>
                <li>Відслідковування статистики по кожному Пассу</li>
                <li>Можливість створення індивідуального тарифу</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

## ua_controller

```
class UaController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
            redirect_to :root
            ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now   
        end
    end

    def solution
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
            redirect_to :root
            ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
        end
    end

    def rates
        @uarates = UaRate.all
        @contact = Contact.new
        if @contact.save
            redirect_to :root
            ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
        end
     end

     def contact
         @contact = Contact.new
         if @contact.save
             redirect_to :root
             ContactsMailer.sample_email(@contact).deliver_now
         end
     end
end
```

## _ua_rates_index.html.erb

```
    <% @uarates.each do |x| %>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-sm-push-3 col-md-push-0 col-xs-12">
            <div class="dashed_container">
                <h5><%= x.title %></h5>
                <ul>
                    <li><%= x.price %></li>
                    <li><%= x.card_type %></li>
                    <li><%= x.card_limit %></li>
                    <li><%= x.sms_count %></li> 
                </ul>
        <a><%= link_to 'Обрати', new_rate_form_path, :class => "content_button_blue"%></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <% end %>
```

## ua_rates_controller

```
class UaRatesController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @uarates = UaRate.all
     end

    def show
        @uarate = UaRate.find params[:id]
    end
end
```

## schema.rb

```
create_table "ua_rates", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "title",      limit: 255
t.string   "card_limit", limit: 255
t.string   "card_type",  limit: 255
t.datetime "created_at",             null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",             null: false
t.string   "price",      limit: 255
t.string   "sms_count",  limit: 255
end


create_table "uas", force: :cascade do |t|
t.datetime "created_at", null: false
t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

## ua_rate.rb

```
class UaRate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :ua
    has_many :rate_forms
end
```

## ua.rb

```
class Ua < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :contacts
    has_many :ua_rates
end
```

Comment: А выложите миграцию, с помощью которой было добавлено поле `price`

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bcb15e2bafa17287376a04231dae9c81  вот тут мои миграции

Comment: Я бы удалил базу данных, снова создал и накатил миграции. Так как миграции удалять нельзя. Вернее можно, но только после их отката.

Comment: Хорошо, я попробую. На локалке норм, а на хостинге эта ошибка... мб что-то с моими конфигами капистрано, или еще где-то. В общем вечером отпишу результат :)